# msbuild error: The property DirectoryName does not exist or was not found

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, visual-studio-2015

This is my first attempt to configure an automated build on Visual Studio Online.

After creating a new build, I queued it to run. The first step was successfully completed (Get sources). Now I am experiencing and error in the build step. Here is a small snippet including the message:

> 782  2015-08-31T16:30:52.4324803Z Executing the powershell script:
>   C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.13\VSBuild.ps1
>
> 783  2015-08-31T16:30:54.0509690Z ##[error]The property DirectoryName
>   does not exist or was not found.
>
> 784  2015-08-31T16:30:54.1321607Z C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe "C:\a\5bc0b6a3\MySolution" /nologo
>   /m /nr:false /fl /flp:"logfile=C:\a\5bc0b6a3\MySolution.log"
>   /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"
>   /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="debug"
>   /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0"
>
> 785  2015-08-31T16:30:54.2859104Z MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project
>   file does not exist.

I have searched for the DirectoryName string in the entire solution with no success and have now idea what it means.

Compilation works fine on my PC and I have no clue where to start looking at.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the real error:

```
785 2015-08-31T16:30:54.2859104Z MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
```

You need to specify the path to a solution file. You can see that you're not:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe
>   **"C:\a\5bc0b6a3\MySolution"** /nologo /m /nr:false /fl
>   /flp:"logfile=C:\a\5bc0b6a3\MySolution.log"
>   /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"
>   /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="debug"
>   /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0"

You can just specify `**\*.sln` for the "Solutions" parameter and it will discover and build all of the solutions in the workspace you mapped. If you need to get more specific, you can do that as well.

Comment: I tried to specify only a project (.csproject), since my solution has several and I do not want to compile all of them. But it seems it is a common approach to get the entire solution to avoid extra configuration. Besides, it seems nugget has some problems to download packages when the solution is not specified. As I am beginning my automated builds, I decided to changed back to **\*.sln as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Side note - nuget in new VSO build pipeline restores packages for all projects in the solution, just configure it as a separate pre-build step rather than "Enable nuget restore on build" option inside the solution. Also I have no issues building separate projects or custom build script there. only one thing that can go wrong in this case - platform and configuration properties often need to be specified explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The folder in which the solution file is should be in or below one of the paths as defined in the mappings under the 'Repository' tab, otherwise the 'Project file does not exist' error will show up also.